# Delete cookie on the client not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp-classic

In *code-behind* of my aspx page I create this cookie:

```
cookieidUserArea = new HttpCookie("idUserArea");
cookieidUserArea.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
cookieidUserArea.Values.Add("", idUserArea.ToString());
Response.Cookies.Add(cookieidUserArea);
```

On the server  where this application in asp net c# is installed it has a page in Classic ASP 3.0.

If I log in application asp net c# and after I try to log in a page in Classic ASP 3.0 I have this error:

```
error '80004005' 
/website/index.asp, line 15
```

In this line:

```
        Response.Cookies("idUserArea").Expires = Date() - 1 
        Response.Cookies("idUserArea") = ""
```

If you manually delete the cookie on the client pc and closed and reopen the browser the page in Classic ASP 3.0 it's worked.

With the code in page in Classic ASP 3.0:

```
        Response.Cookies("idUserArea").Expires = Date() - 1 
        Response.Cookies("idUserArea") = ""
```

I tried delete all cookies without success.

This is the cookie txt file :

```
idUserArea=mS10webxx.xxx.xxx/1024177534809630460199408711376030460190*
```

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using DateTime.Now and subtracting time off that?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx

For example: Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);

Comment: thank you but the problem is in a page Classic ASP 3.0, if tried your suggestion I have error.

Comment: I didn't think of that, because .NET has the DateTime.Now class/method I thought it would work.